# memcpy in C# with different dataType

Tags: c#, .net

I am porting a c++ code into c#.There are 2 structures, as explained
below.
// Must be a total of 180 bytes

```
typedef struct MAINTENANCE_PARAM`
{
    BYTE bCommand;
    BYTE bSubCommand;
    USHORT usDataLength;
    union  // Must be no larger than 176 bytes
    {
        MyStruct1 myStruct1;
                MyStruct2 myStruct2;
        BYTE bDummy[176];
    } data;
} MAINTENANCE_PARAM;

typedef struct _OCI_PARAM {
    SHORT  sType;          // Size: 2
    LONG   lValue;         //  4
    SHORT  sScale;         //  2
    LONG   lValueTabIdx;   //  4
} OCI_PARAM[OCI_MAXPARAM];    //Size: OCI_MAXPARAM = 15  // 15 * 12 = 180
```

My code uses the memcpy in the following fashion.

```
MAINTENANCE_PARAM maintainanceParam;
    OCI_PARAM ociParam       

    // Copy recieved structure to correct format
    memcpy((void*)& maintainanceParam, (void*) ociParam, sizeof(OCI_PARAM));
```

As I know there is no code for memcpy in the C#. So how can I port the
above code into the C#. I am new to C#. I don't know much regarding
the C#. So can anybody tell me how exactly I can implement the above
line of code in C#. I need to copy 180 bytes from one structure to another structure object with different datatype
Thanks in Advance for any help.
Regards,
Ashish

Comment: You can't. Do you need these structures to connect another legacy app/system/library or are you reimplementing everything?

Comment: I need these structures as it is :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `StructLayoutAttribute` and `FieldOffsetAttribute` for your structs so that you can layout your fields explicitly, then import `RtlMoveMemory` (P/Invoke). You can modify the signature to take any pointer type (in unsafe context) or use the standard signature on PInvoke.net.

```
unsafe class Program {

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlMoveMemory", SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern void MoveMemory(void* dest, void* src, int size);

    static  void Main(string[] args) {

        Maintenance_Param p1 = new Maintenance_Param();
        p1.bCommand = 2;
        p1.bSubCommand = 3;
        p1.usDataLength = 3;
        p1.myStruct1 = new MyStruct1();

        Maintenance_Param p2 = new Maintenance_Param();
        MoveMemory(&p2, &p1, sizeof(Maintenance_Param));
    }
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Maintenance_Param {

    // fields should be private and be accessed over properties ...
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte bCommand;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(1)]
    public byte bSubCommand;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(2)]
    public ushort usDataLength;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(4)]
    public MyStruct1 myStruct1;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(4)]
    public MyStruct2 myStruct2;
}

public struct MyStruct1 {
    int value;
}

public struct MyStruct2 {
    int value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Malio for detailed post. I used the Field offset to have control over memory and replicate Union in C. But I don't want to use Dllimport in these case. Can we have some better solution in C# other than pInvoke.

Comment: @Ashish - have a look at the link 6opuc posted below

Answer (score 1):

MemCpy DOES exist in .NET! Try googling for OpCodes.Cpblk. Here is an example: http://www.abstractpath.com/weblog/2009/04/memcpy-in-c.html

Comment: And then try benchmarking it on x86. And then try not using it unless you're either 64-bit only, or you're at least going to probe and fallback to something else on x86.

Comment: That's not far off what I found; note that `cpblk` is always worse than `memcpy` on x86, and inferior to his `CustomCopy` except for a range of block-sizes of 512-2048. My own tests differed in that I had a more heavily unwound C#-only equivalent to `CustomCopy` so it was beating `memcpy` until around 400bytes, and there was no point where it wasn't beating `cpblk`. On x86-64 I found like him that `cpblk` always wins (.NET and Mono), even against my better C#-only method. On Mono on Windows, with x86, the three are much closer to each other with `cpblk` being a close winner.

Comment: Incidentally, one issue I'd have with those benchmarks, is that it doesn't try any non-power-of-two block sizes. Since memory operations can be particularly good or particularly bad on power-of-two blocks, it's worth trying both sizes that hit those boundaries, and sizes that don't. Here though, I found much the same as in those charts, bar my better C#-only method.
All that said, cpblk is definitely the way to go for anything other than with x86 using the Microsoft framework, so I'll be wrapping it up in something handy and publishing a NuGet package soon.

Comment: Sure. https://bitbucket.org/JonHanna/mnemosyne is it. I'll want to tidy up a wee bit more (some of the x86-specific stuff should be in a separate class, for one thing) and add more tests before making a NuGet package, but I wouldn't claim to be great at CIL (the whole point of packaging this is to be able to just use it from C# and not worry about CIL), so I'd welcome feedback on the code.

Comment: Never saw so much IL code written by a human being) Super-hardcore!

Comment: Well, I used a T4 template for the second largest bit, because it was repetitive and boring.